# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body - Discord slash commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

There are many questions for the `DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body` however none of the answers seem to help.
When using `message.channel.send(embed)`, the embed works as it should with no errors. However when trying to send the embed through a slash command leads to quite a few issues.

Index.js:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();
require('dotenv').config();
client.login(process.env.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    const createAPIMessage = async (interaction, content) => {
        const { data, files } = await Discord.APIMessage.create(
            client.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id),
            content
        )
            .resolveData()
            .resolveFiles()

        return { ...data, files }
    }

    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
        const command = (interaction.data.name).toLowerCase();
        const args = interaction.data.options;

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            var commandFile = require(`./commands/${file}`);
            if (command == commandFile.name) {
                commandFile.execute(interaction, client, async function (message) {
                    if (typeof message == 'object')
                        message = await createAPIMessage(interaction, message);
                    client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                        data: {
                            type: 4,
                            data: {
                                content: message
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

commands/urban.js

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const urban = require('urban');

module.exports = {
    name: 'urban',
    description: 'Search the dictionary for a word',
    options: [{ name: 'word', description: 'A word to search in the dictionary.', type: 3, required: true }],
    execute(interaction, client, callback) {
        //console.log(interaction)
        urban(interaction.data.options[0].value).first(async json => {
            if (!json) return callback('The word ' + interaction.data.options[0].value + ' does not exist');
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(json.word)
                .setDescription((json.definition).split('[').join('').split(']').join(''))
                .setFooter('Billybobbeep is not responsible for what you search | Written by: ' + (json.author || 'Unknown'))
                .addField('Upvotes', json.thumbs_up || 0, true)
                .addField('Downvotes', json.thumb_down || 0, true)
            callback(embed)
        });
    }
}
```

Full error received:

```
(node:16584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
data.content: Could not interpret "{'tts': False, 'embed': {'title': 'hi', 'type': 'rich', 'description': "testing", 'url': None, 'timestamp': None, 'color': None, 'fields': [{'name': 'Upvotes', 'value': '319', 'inline': True}, {'name': 'Downvotes', 'value': '0', 'inline': True}], 'thumbnail': None, 'image': None, 'author': None, 'footer': 'None'}, 'embeds': [{'title': 'hi', 'type': 'rich', 'description': "testing", 'url': None, 'timestamp': None, 'color': None, 'fields': [{'name': 'Upvotes', 'value': '319', 'inline': True}, {'name': 'Downvotes', 'value': '0', 'inline': True}], 'thumbnail': None, 'image': None, 'author': None, 'footer': 'None' }], 'files': []}" as string.
```

Comment: You're passing in an object, the method expects a string

Comment: It looks like the description is in double-quotes while everything else is in single-quotes. The JSON string is initialized as with double quotes, so when it encounters a set of double quotes inside of the string, it interprets that as the string ending.

Comment: @mjm0813 The JSON string is only for the error and the double quotes do not affect the object in any way.

Comment: @Elitezen How do you convert an embed object to string then? Many solutions provide the same code as in my question

Comment: Try [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although [MrMythical's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67528574/14267427) probably would have worked, my problem was that I was trying to send an embed as the content.
Full Solution:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const client = new Discord.Client();
require('dotenv').config();
client.login(process.env.token);

client.on('ready', () => {
    const createAPIMessage = async (interaction, content) => {
        const { data, files } = await Discord.APIMessage.create(
            client.channels.resolve(interaction.channel_id),
            content
        )
            .resolveData()
            .resolveFiles()

        return { ...data, files }
    }

    client.ws.on('INTERACTION_CREATE', async interaction => {
        const command = (interaction.data.name).toLowerCase();
        const args = interaction.data.options;

        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            var commandFile = require(`./commands/${file}`);
            if (command == commandFile.name) {
                commandFile.execute(interaction, client, async function(message) {
                    let data = {
                        content: message
                    }
                    if (typeof message == 'object')
                        data = await createAPIMessage(interaction, message);
                    client.api.interactions(interaction.id, interaction.token).callback.post({
                        data: {
                            type: 4,
                            data
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Define all embeds as `data` instead of anything inside the JSON data its-self.

Answer (score 0):

Embeds use their own property

```
data: {
embeds: [embed1];
}
```

You should note that it is an array, and this was just an example, replace embed1 with whatever embed you want. Don’t worry, you don’t need to make it look weird by adding data.content because discord makes it so only data.content **or** data.embeds are required. This means yes, this embed *can* be the full content